# In what specific way has the the EU "turned [its] rules upside down and inside out" on medicines in Northern Ireland?

Tags: european-union, brexit, healthcare, northern-ireland

In response to UK government accusations that the EU has been inflexible on medicines under the Northern Ireland protocol (see e.g. Boris Johnson's [charge](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/66595/18373) on 30 cancer drugs) the EU ambassador to the UK has been [quoted](https://www.irishexaminer.com/news/politics/arid-40326692.html) as saying:

> “In some cases, notably on medicines, we have completely turned our rules upside down and inside out to find a solid solution to an outstanding challenge,” Mr Vale de Almeida writes in a column in The Daily Telegraph.

But the article lacks some concrete example of this supposed EU flexibility. Is there a concrete example of what the EU has done on this in terms of turning "upside down and inside out " its rules? ([Another](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-northern-ireland-57682071) BBC article mentions that the EU plans to introduce some legislation on this... in August. It's not clear if that's what ambassador Almeida is talking about though...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the UK want to remove medicines from the scope of the Northern Ireland protocol?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/66592/why-does-the-uk-want-to-remove-medicines-from-the-scope-of-the-northern-ireland)

Comment: @JoeC this seems to be the opposite question asking what the EU has done to accommodate the Northern Ireland situation.

Comment: Ah, the headline confused me.  I've edited it to clarify and retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Ambassador Almeida was echoing Vice President Maroš Šefčovič in using the "upside down and inside out" soundbite - he used the same language in a [press statement](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/detail/en/SPEECH_21_3366) the day before (June 30th), where he unveiled a list of 'practical solutions' proposed to facilitate the implementation of the Protocol.

> Turning to the second part of our package: we have put together a
> significant set of practical solutions, helping implement the Protocol
> and facilitating the everyday life of communities in Northern Ireland.
> **On medicines – something I personally take very seriously in this time
> of pandemic – the Commission will table a legislative proposal in the
> early autumn that will secure their continued, long-term supply from
> Great Britain to Northern Ireland.** This would allow for instance, for
> the continued availability of generic medicines in Northern Ireland –
> something of particular importance to the NHS. We have also identified
> a solution to ease the movement of guide dogs accompanying persons
> travelling from Great Britain to Northern Ireland. Similarly, we will
> simplify the movement of livestock, by removing the need for
> re-tagging when animals move multiple times between Great Britain and
> Northern Ireland. Lastly, drivers from the UK will no longer need to
> show the motor insurance Green Card when entering the EU, and this
> waiver will be particularly helpful for Northern Irish motorists
> crossing the border into Ireland. I am convinced that these
> forthcoming solutions are a true testament to our commitment to the
> people of Northern Ireland and to the Good Friday (Belfast) Agreement.
> They are also an unquestionable response to those in the UK suggesting
> that the EU is inflexible or too legalistic. **Because in some cases,
> notably on medicines, we have completely turned our rules upside down
> and inside out to find a solid solution to an outstanding challenge.**

These solutions are outlined in more detail [here](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/detail/en/ip_21_3324), and although the legislative proposals don't seem to have been published yet, the outline gives some indication of the EU's proposals.

In particular, on medicines:

> The Commission has identified a creative solution to ensure the
> continued long-term supply of medicines from Great Britain to Northern
> Ireland. The solution involves the EU changing its own rules so that
> regulatory compliance functions for medicines authorised by the UK for
> the Northern Ireland market, in accordance with the Protocol, may be
> located in Great Britain, subject to specific conditions ensuring that
> the medicines concerned are not further distributed in the EU Internal
> Market. The Commission will put forward a legislative proposal in the
> early autumn in order to be able to finish the legislative process on
> time.